# Couchbase Client Configuration for enhanced durability

Tags: java, couchbase

I am trying to implement ATPlus scan consistency within my couchbase java application. I have updated my queries to include the `consistentWith(mutationState)`:

```
RawJsonDocument courseJsonDocument = toRawJsonDocument(course, true);
RawJsonDocument insertedJsonDocument = bucket.insert(courseJsonDocument);
MutationState insertMutationState = MutationState.from(insertedJsonDocument);
.....
N1qlQuery.simple(GET_COURSE_BY_ID_QUERY, N1qlParams.build().consistentWith(mutationState));
```

I'm trying to achieve read-your-own-write, but when I run the query immediately after inserting the document, nothing is found, so I must be doing something wrong. I think what I am missing is actually enabling enhanced durability on the client configuration.

I see examples of how to do it in .NET, but I can't figure out how to 'enable enhanced durability' in JAVA. Here is my cluster configuration:

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
        .queryServiceConfig(QueryServiceConfig.create(1, 100))
        .mutationTokensEnabled(true)
        .observeIntervalDelay(Delay.fixed(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS))
        .connectTimeout(timeout)
        .build(), 
        clusterHost);
```